# Is it possible to debug an application using the built-in Terminal

Tags: debugging, terminal, visual-studio-2019

By default in VS2019 when pressing F5 to debug a console app, VS spins up a new CMD and runs the code in it. Is it possible to have VS use the built-in terminal instead?

Comment: I think you cannot get what you want. The console is just like a specific service rather than a real `cmd.exe` or `developer command prompt for VS`. The project type is designed by that, so you cannot change it.

Comment: Hi, no update, I've accepted your answer although it's hardly a satisfactory outcome, hard to believe they went through the trouble of adding a built in terminal without giving us the means to debug console apps in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to debug an application using the built-in Terminal

**I think you cannot get you want as you wish.**

**Although** the Console window shows that it is from `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`, in fact, it is a special service(rather than the real `cmd.exe`)  which implemented, for example of Win7, with `conhost.exe`.

From your description, probably, you want to run some commands on it like `developer command prompt for VS2019` rather than the default one when you debug this console application,

**however**, the project type of the console application is designed by that. There is no operation and **Microsoft** does not support changing it due to some reasons.

**Suggestion**

**If you still want this feature**, you could suggest a feature on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and the Team will consider your thought carefully. Besides, you can share the link with us here. Anyone who is interested in it will vote it so that it will capture the attention of the Team.

**Update 1**

To add more detailed info:

**Actually**, there is a function to debug your console application in any extra program like powershell or any other executable program.

In my side, I used Powershell:

[image]

`ConsoleApp11.exe` is just the name of your current project's output file.

And then click **Start Debugging**, it can start **powershell** at the beginning, but it will break the whole process, such as, you cannot hit the breakpoint and and back off immediately.

**Also**, **VS built-in terminal**(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`) is just a bat file rather than a executable file(`.exe` file), it is also fundamentally unattainable.

**And that's why I told you at the beginning that this is not going to happen.**

As [x0n said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970028/12450747), console subsystem is just an app framework offerring common service with `cmd.exe`, when the project runs, it is not actually running CMD, so it is not realistic to replace it.

**Just as I suggested**, you could send your request to the VS Team and hope they could give you a satisfactory reply.